# How to increase height of an element upwards?

Tags: html, css

The HTML Code:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
</ul>
```

If i add one more `li` in the list, its height grows downwards. But i would like keep the list bottom static and increase its height upwards.

**Update:**
I am trying to keep a small bar in the bottom of browser window always. When user picks something, the bar will show the item. If it more than one item, the container has to auto increase its height upwards.

How to do it?

Any suggestions would be appreciative!

Thanks!

Comment: scroll the window? this does not make a lot of sense as posted...

Comment: Wait a minute... As Randy said, this does not make a lot of sense. Isn't all the position relative to the others? If you want the bottom static, what will you do when you add too many tags? If scroll up then that's the same as fix the top.

Comment: I am trying to make it as a widget which stays at the bottom of the screen always. I wish it to be stayed in bottom even if user scrolls. But when i add more item it has to increase its height upwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I guess your list should be in absolute position width a specified `bottom`.

Comment: I am trying to make it like `bottom bar` in many websites. It stays in bottom always.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is set the bottom property like this

```
<ul style="position:absolute;bottom:1px;">
         <li>A</li>
         <li>B</li>
         <li>C</li>
         <li>D</li>
         <li>E</li>
         <li>F</li>
     </ul>
```

This will put the block at the bottom of whatever block it is in.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be to make the `ul` `position:absolute`. And in your script when you add an item subtract the x position by the height of the item. Of course `position:absolute` would take the list out of the normal flow.